# Background-color Css

Tags: css

I am using bootstrap 3.0 and the following is my HTML code , I am facing a problem with the background color.

HTML code

```
<div class="container" id="pictures">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>Collection</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code (I have targeted the `H1` tag using this css code)

```
#pictures h1 {
    padding:10px 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size:60px;
    background-color: #f92735;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 60px 370px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: -65px;
}
```

Heres the problem , as i size down my browser horizontally , the background color disappears . can somebody tell me why ?

Comment: Where is `#pictures` element?

Comment: <div class="container" id="pictures">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>Collection</h1>
    </div>
</div>

</div>

@panther i coded this in bootstrap 3.0 .

Comment: Is the html you provided a descendant of the container `#pictures`?

Comment: Maybe it gets overridden by some media query?

Comment: try background-color: #color !important;

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache there is nothing wrong with that CSS. http://jsfiddle.net/3s7zg/

Comment: Thanks ashley for you response , the problem exists on a few pc's i have tried , @aravind yeah , i taught it might be a media query issue .

Comment: @Vucko the background-color is not dissapearing , its reducing in size as i reduce my browser size horizontally . where as the text remains the same size . so the bg color is not getting orver-ridden , the problem is its reducing in size when i don't want it to .

Comment: @AshleyMedway the problem occurs on a few desktop systems that i have checked , not just by computer !

Comment: Ok! The problem is the margin you have applied for your div. As the window size gets smaller, so does the h1 tag area. Here the text size remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem come from the following styles you have applied for `h1`

```
 margin: 60px 370px;
```

It means it required minimum (370+370) width to show your h1 tag. Reduce the margin to less number then you can see it in small screens also.

```
#pictures h1 {
padding:10px 0;
color: #fff;
font-size:60px;
background-color: #f92735;
text-align: center;
margin: 60px 30px;
border-radius: 10px;
margin-top: -65px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ns6MJ/)

Comment: Thats right suresh ! thats the problem . Thank you .

Comment: Done suresh. ticked it